# Maven - load all jars inside a system folder

Tags: maven, dependency-management

Is there a way we can load all the jar files inside a folder, as dependencies in a maven project.

So that, I do not have to mention each and every jar files in pom.xml, just mention or tell maven to pick all the jar files from folder 'x' and build the system.

**Is this supported by maven?**

I think this is supported by ant. Not sure whether gradle supports either.

Comment: I doubt it. You can reference single files from the disk, but it should only be done in special circumstances. Usually, you use a repository and put all references in your pom.

Comment: You seemed to misunderstand the Maven concept. Dependencies will be provided by a a Maven repository (usually Maven Central) and will be downloaded from there and being cached into a local cache). If you have more jars you should define a parent pom or a so called bom which defines the versions of those artifacts in a reusable way....Maven is not Ant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies

you see that you can reference single files, but there is no mechanism for directories. As I mentioned in the comment, using the disk is discouraged in general.

If you need the same set of dependencies in many projects, you can write a pom for that and use it (as parent or by setting a dependency to it).